# Swift - check if instance is one of multiple types

Tags: swift

Given classes:

```
class A: Base {}
class B: Base {}
class C: Base {}
class D: Base {}
```

and an array of types:

```
let types = [A, C]
```

how can I check if a variable passed to a method is one of the types from the array?
Meaning if my variable - let's call it `typeVariable` - is of type `A` or `C`.

I know I can do:

```
if typeVariable is A || typeVariable is C {
    ...
}
```

but I would like a more concise code.

Comment: How is typeVariable declared and are A, B and C the only types that inherits from Base? Could you do `if typeVariable is Base` instead?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson actually no, but that may not have been obvious, so I've edited my question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `type(of:)` and `.contains`:

```
let types = [A.self, C.self]

let test = A()

if types.contains(where: { $0 == type(of:test) }) {
    print("Here")
}
```

Comment: I just figured it out myself.. your answer is correct, thanks!